# RollBack Installation if custom action fails [After InstallFinalise] -Basic Msi -Installshield 2012

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012, basic-msi

I am creating a **basic msi installer** using **installshield 2012 spring professional** , here i have a custom dialog to collect some data from the user based on which i call a custom dll action to create a database inside the installation folder .

I have a scheduled a dll custom action to run *After InstallFinalise* , I want to check the return value from the dll and if the value indicates a failure i need to abort and rollback the installation process.

I have managed to catch the error and abort the installation but the issue is with the rollback .. Right now the installation aborts but the files are already created . How do i get the installation rolled back ? Is it possible .. Any ideas ??

Comment: I thought this should happen automatically if you return non-zero code from your action. What are the settings for your action? Probably you need to have set check return code.

Comment: The rollback action based on error works automatically only if the error is returned before _installfinalise_ , but the issue is before installfinalise, the files and folders are not created so i am executing the dll action after installfinalise ..

Comment: mistyped install finalise as installfiles .. mybad !! :(

Comment: I got you. Truth is I am a bit doomed to be using installshield 2008 and I saw some issues with uninstall - if install location is not an ASCII path uninstall would not remove some of the files from some of the components. That is why I wrote my own custom actions to clean up the files. I certainly hope this issue has been resolved in later versions of the software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to rollback after InstallFinalize.  InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize mark the boundries of the windows installer transaction.

I suggest reading and understanding:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)

Comment: I understood it is not possible , i just wanted other solutions that are possible like a custom action to delete the files and folders or to initiate the uninstall automatically from the installer ..